# Remove preventDefault() On A Click Event After 2 Seconds

Tags: javascript, events, settimeout, preventdefault

I have a preventDefault() method on some links that I would like to remove after 2 seconds.

I'm trying to both work out how to remove the preventDefault() - which stops the links from working, but also how to do it so it happens after 2 seconds.

I thought I could do it by removing the 'link' class the initial forEach loop happens on, but alas this doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/VwPJNGE

```js
var link = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

// prevent default on all specific links
link.forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

// remove prevent Default
function allowLinks() {
  link.forEach(function (item) {
    item.classList.remove("link");
  });
}

setTimeout(function() {
  allowLinks();
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://google.com" class="link">Make me work after 2 seconds</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `link` class won't accomplish your goal because the event listener is associated with the DOM element, not the class. In other words, the class name is the means by which you accessed the DOM elements but the class itself holds no association with the event listener.

One option is to remove the event listener itself after two seconds. You can do this by defining the event listener function in a higher scope and the using the `removeEventListener` method.

```js
var link = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

const listener = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};

// prevent default on all specific links
link.forEach(function (item) {
 item.addEventListener("click", listener);
});

// remove prevent Default
function allowLinks() {
  link.forEach(function (item) {
    item.removeEventListener("click", listener);
  });
}

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("links allowed!");
  allowLinks();
}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" class="link">Make me work after 2 seconds</a>
```

Comment: Hi @nick - I actually tried doing removeEventListener() initially, but I did it as     item.removeEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
    }); 
inside the allowLinks() function and it didn't work. Do you know why it only works when you assign that function to a variable/const ?

Comment: Yes, the event listener you remove must have _referential equality_ with the initial event listener.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rely on the classes for state on this type of scenario:

```js
var root = document.querySelector("<parent element selector>"); // e.g. nav, .post

root.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("link")) {
    e.target.classList.remove("link");
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.classList.add("link");
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    console.log("Cancelling click:", e.target);
    return e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work - although this may be because you've abbreviated the code which is confusing me. Should the initial `item` that you've put be the `link` variable?